# Angular ui bootstrap accordion not working if add dependency..?

Tags: jquery, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-accordion

I have copied the examples for Angular ui accordion from many sites but none of the code is working. When i use that code is plunker or any similar thing it is working but not working in my pc. Please help me.

This is my html code

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en-US" ng-app="myModule">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Accordion test</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.0.5/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/0.4.0/ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="example.js"></script>
  <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
<div ng-controller="AccordionDemoCtrl">
  <label class="checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="oneAtATime">
    Open only one at a time
  </label>

  <accordion close-others="oneAtATime">
    <accordion-group heading="Static Header">
      This content is straight in the template.
    </accordion-group>
    <accordion-group heading="{{group.title}}" ng-repeat="group in groups">
      {{group.content}}
    </accordion-group>
    <accordion-group heading="Dynamic Body Content">
      <p>The body of the accordion group grows to fit the contents</p>
        <button class="btn btn-small" ng-click="addItem()">Add Item</button>
        <div ng-repeat="item in items">{{item}}</div>
    </accordion-group>
  </accordion>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

and this is js code

```
angular.module('myModule', ['ui.bootstrap'])

function AccordionDemoCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.oneAtATime = true;

  console.log('bla');

  $scope.groups = [
    {
      title: "Dynamic Group Header - 1",
      content: "Dynamic Group Body - 1"
    },
    {
      title: "Dynamic Group Header - 2",
      content: "Dynamic Group Body - 2"
    }
  ];

  $scope.items = ['Item 1', 'Item 2', 'Item 3'];

  $scope.addItem = function() {
    var newItemNo = $scope.items.length + 1;
    $scope.items.push('Item ' + newItemNo);
  };
}
```

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're not attaching your `AccordionDemoCtrl` controller to your `myModule` module. You need something like this:

```
 angular.module('myModule').controller("AccordionDemoCtrl", AccordionDemoCtrl);
```

Put that line under (or above) the current definition for `AccordionDemoCtrl` and that should fix things for you.